# How do I upload a file using ajax with django?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, file, upload

I'm new to this. Could you show me how to send a file to server using ajax. I could submit to my server a String, but I don't know how would ajax handle a File?

upload_stuff.js

```
$(document).on('submit', '#CustomerRequest', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/create_request',
    data:{
        ajax_file1:$('#html_file1').val(),
        ajax_file2:$('#html_file2').val(),
        ajax_file2:$('#html_file3').val(),               
                    ...
```

view.py

```
def create_request (request):
    if request.method == "POST":
            server_file1 = request.FILES('ajax_files1')
            server_file2 = request.FILES('ajax_file2')
            server_file3 = request.FILES('ajax_file3')
```

I do have csrf_token and and enctype="multipart/form-data" on my html form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this and it works fine, Hope it works for you too.

First create a relevant form in your forms.py file which would look like this:

```
from django import forms

class FileForm(forms.Form):
   file = forms.FileField(required=True)
```

In your html file it would look like:

```
    <div>
        <form id="file_form" action="/application/new_file/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label class="btn btn-info btn-xs" for="subgroup_file" style="background-color: #042d63;border-color: #dddddd;border-width: 2px;color: white;padding: 5px 21px;" id="send_file" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto top" title="Choose The File">
                <input id="the_file" name="file" type="file" style="display:none;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></span>
            </label>
            <input type="submit" id="file_form_submit" class="my-small-btn" value="Submit" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto top" title="Submit File">
        </form>   
    </div>
```

then the `id=file_form` can trigger this:

```
    $('#file_form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this); //get data of form elements for submission
        formData.append('sg_id', '{{ sg_id }}'); //add additional data to form's data

        $.ajax({
            url: "/application/new_file/",
            type: "POST",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if(! data.created){
                    location.reload();
                } else if(! data.valid_extension){
                    swal({
                        title: 'You can only submit PDF files',
                        text: '',
                        icon: 'error',
                        timer: 5000,
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Here I have also added a [sweet alert](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/) which informs  the user he/she is only allowed to upload PDF files. The URL finally takes you from `urls.py` to a fucntion named `saveFile` in `views.py` which would something like this:

```
def saveFile(request):
    if(request.user != AnonymousUser()):
        try:
            if request.method == 'POST':
                file_form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
                sg_id = request.POST.get("sg_id")
                subgroup = SubGroup.objects.get(pk=sg_id)
                if(file_form.is_valid()):
                    file = file_form.cleaned_data["file"]
                    name = str(file)
                    f, extension = os.path.splitext(name)
                    if(extension in valid_extensions):
                        obj = Files.objects.create(
                            file = file,
                            subgroup = subgroup,
                            creator = request.user,
                            created_at = datetime.datetime.now(),
                            name = name
                        )
.......
.......
.......
```

The `SubGroup` and `Files` are objects defined in `models.py` which connect you to the database.

Comment: Is there a way to submit other info too, not just file?

Comment: It could be anything you want. What do you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this might be helpful or not, but in JQuery the `$('#fileinput').val()` doesn't return "Ajax friendly" file data, try using `document.getElementById('fileinput').files[0];` to get the file data using raw javascript and try to add these options on the ajax request 
`contentType: false,
 processData: false,`